# Python: how to get error from list[-1]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to return an error for the index value [-1]?

```
>>>l=[1,2,3]
>>>l[-1]
error:list index out of range
```

Comment: No, it's a valid index. It means "access the last element". You would need to wrap the access in an if statement to check if the index is >=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for the built-in list type, but you can define your own class that has stricter indexing rules:

```
>>> class StrictList(list):
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...             if index < 0:
...                     raise IndexError("negative integers are forbidden")
...             return list.__getitem__(self, index)
...
>>> seq = StrictList([1,2,3])
>>> seq[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getitem__
IndexError: 'negative integers are forbidden'
```

Comment: Note however that `list` methods do *not* call the `__getitem__` method to access elements. For instance with the definition above `seq[-1] = 0` doesn't yield any error.

Comment: You should subclass [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence), rather than `list`, to make sure you're implementing all of the appropriate methods for that protocol.

Comment: The problem with this is that I will have a large number of indexes and decrement to 0. If possible I would like to avoid the extra processing power required for an if statement.

Comment: Well, if you're only going to decrement to zero and not to negative one, why do you need `seq[-1]` to raise an error? Just use a regular list.